# Text is appearing overtop image in some browsers

Tags: css

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="recipeblock clearfix">
    <img src="img/ph_recipes-001.jpg" />
    <h1>Pineapple Cola Ham</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum master walkie havenport.</p>
    <div class="recipebottom">

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium" g:plusone:count="false"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal" pi:pinit:url="http://www.addthis.com/features/pinterest" pi:pinit:media="http://www.addthis.com/cms-content/images/features/pinterest-lg.png"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4e45294b7aa0c81e"></script>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>PREP</th>
                <th>COOK</th>
                <th>READY IN</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10min</td>
                <td>30min</td>
                <td>40min</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
div.recipeblock{position:relative;margin-bottom:30px;}
div.recipeblock img{float:left;margin-right:30px;}
div.recipebottom{position:absolute;left:363px;bottom:0;}

table{font-family:franklin_gothic_fsMdCn;text-align:center;}
table th{width:100px;color:#eedda6;background-color:#977e50;font-weight:normal;}
table th{padding:2px 0 1px 0;font-size:0.9em;border-right:1px solid #fff;}
table th:first-child{border-left:1px solid #977e50;}
table th:last-child{border-right:1px solid #977e50;}
table td{width:100px;padding:6px 0 3px 0;color:#977e50;font-size:1.3em;border-left:1px solid #977e50;border-bottom:1px solid #977e50;}
table td:last-child{border-right:1px solid #977e50;}
```

The title Pineapple Cola Ham (the H1 tag) should be floating to the right of the photo. I have tested this in six different browsers (both Windows and Macintosh).

Yet, my client is seeing what is in the following screenshot, the title is overtop the image. He is using the same browser I am (Safari on a MacBook Pro). He has done several hard refreshes of the browser, yet still sees this. I cannot duplicate the problem!

I have no idea what could be causing this, I would really appreciate anyone's advice. Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please include ALL code relevant to your question. Do not link to a live site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Yeah, css for all those elements, plus the relevant html please.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited my original post and put in all the relevant HTML and CSS.